# Behaviour of set that stores tuples, Python

Tags: python, set, tuples

I'd like to create a set of tuples, but have been encountering some behaviour that I don't understand. For example:

```
    >>> b=set()
    >>> b.add((1,2))
    >>> b.add((4,5))
    >>> b
    {(1, 2), (4, 5)}
    # all fine
    >>> f = set((1,2,3))
    >>> f
    {1, 2, 3}
    # ?
    >>> b=set().add((1,2))
    >>> b
    # b is empty?
```

Can someone help me understand this behaviour? My understanding is that tuples are hashable, so I should be able to store them in a set. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: `set().add()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing different things.

- `set()` takes an iterable and creates a set from the *contents*.

  If you want to create a set with a single tuple, pass in an iterable with that single tuple:

  ```
  >>> set([(1, 2, 3)])
  {(1, 2, 3)}
  ```

  It's better to use the `{...}` set literal syntax:

  ```
  >>> {(1, 2, 3)}
  {(1, 2, 3)}
  ```
- `set().add()` updates a set in-place and returns `None`.

  If you wanted to create an empty set and add to that, do so in two separate expressions:

  ```
  >>> b = set()
  >>> b.add((1, 2))
  >>> b
  {(1, 2)}
  ```

Neither of these two issues have anything to do with tuples being hashable.

Answer (score 3):

`set((1, 2, 3))` means a set of `(1, 2, 3)`'s *elements*. A set whose only element is `(1, 2, 3)` is `{(1, 2, 3)}`, not `set((1, 2, 3))`.

`set.add` modifies a set in place. If you want to add to a set, you need to store the set itself, then `add` to it, not store `add`'s return value.